# Json column SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (to connect to SQL Server) and I have a table called `mrct_products.BakedProduct` with 3 columns:

```
 1. Column1 ProductID
 2. Column2 Status
 3. Column3 TechnicalSpecs
```

Column `Column3` contains a table containing a huge json with a lot of values. Here is an example of a line:

```
[{"Name":"Color","Value":"Red"},{"Name":"Type","Value":"Naturally sweet"}]
```

I want to make a query and ask for the Color.
Here is my try but the color returns empty

```
select ProductId,json_value(TechnicalSpecs, '$.Color') as color
from mrct_products.BakedProduct
```

Comment: Does `SELECT ProductId, (SELECT Value FROM OPENJSON(TechnicalSpecs) WHERE Name = 'Color') AS color FROM mrct_products.BakedProduct` work?

Answer (score 0):

any reason why its initially designed as json? as far as I see, its seems 'okay' to use the db columns for those json data. or you can just create another table for that, it will be easier to maintain those,

If you really like to store json, then I recommend storing it using document based repository e.g mongodb and have the mongodb data id mapped from your BakedProduct

Comment: I really dont know why it is like that.It is not my table but The query returns empty for some reason.Please help

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the unexpected results is the fact, that the parsed text is a JSON array of JSON objects, not a JSON object with a `$.status` key/value pair. You need a different statement using `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema and an `APPLY` operator to parse the JSON and filter the results:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE BakedProduct (
   ProductID int,
   Status varchar(100),
   TechnicalSpecs varchar(1000)
)
INSERT INTO BakedProduct (ProductID, Status, TechnicalSpecs)
VALUES (1, 'Status', '[{"Name":"Color","Value":"Red"},{"Name":"Type","Value":"Naturally sweet"}]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT p.ProductId, p.Status, j.[Name], j.[Value]
FROM BakedProduct p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(p.TechnicalSpecs) WITH (
   [Name] varchar(100) '$.Name',
   [Value] varchar(100) '$.Value'
) j
WHERE j.[Name] = 'Color'
```

Result:

```
ProductId   Status  Name    Value
1           Status  Color   Red
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you want to make a query and ask for the Color.You could try the following code to get it.

```
select ProductID,Status,Name,Value 
from BakedProduct
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TechnicalSpecs) WITH(
       Name varchar(50)
     , Value varchar(50)
     ) j
         where j.Name='Color'
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Looking at it, the JSON field is weird... it's normaly created as:

```
{key:value}
```

In format

```
 {String:Any}
```

So, the beginning of your field should be:

```
[{"Color","Red"},{"Type","Naturally sweet"}....
```

Note that is not incorrect your JSON, only is more complicated that it can be.

Returning to your question you can use OPENJSON in a procedure:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json= youfieldhere
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json);
```

If your field is, for semplify it, {"Color","Red"},{"Type","Naturally sweet"}, the result would be a new table like:

### Key | Value

Color  | Red
Type   | Naturally swift

(I have to undestand how to make table in answers)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know it is writen in a wierd way but I have to use it as it is and I dont want to use a procidure.I want a simply query like the one I tried , it just need a little correction